# Magento - unable to refund

Tags: magento

When attempting a full refund in Magento 1.7.0.2 (there is no Adjustment Refund or Adjustment Fee being applied) but we are receiving the following message

```
This Refund would exceed the amount of the original transaction.
```

As a test, we have a staging site setup where we have replicated and refunded the order without any issues.

Below are the order totals in Magento

```
Subtotal       £7.49
Discount       £1.12 (15% off)
Tax            £2.07
Shipping       £4.95
Grand Total    £11.32
```

Logging into the Payment Provider system, show the grand total as £11.31

Any ideas about what might be happening and what we can look into would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Which payment module are you using? Rounding issues might occur, if the payment module calls `$quote->collectTotals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refunds can only be performed if the amount is equal to or less then the original purchased amount. If it does not meet this criteria you cannot issue that refund.

Comment: Understood. The issue is more to do with why is Magento showing the order total as £11.32, yet the Payment Provider is showing as £11.31. There is a rounding issue somewhere and I am yet to workout where.